# Is there a good way to manage all events being fired on $rootScope so you don't end up with events with the same name?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I know events can be very ugly fast, but is there a good way to manage or control the string names of events, so programmers will not be able to give the same string name event while working on different components?

Comment: I have a [wrapper created to manage the publish/subscribe in this answer of mine)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274563/angularjs-communication-between-directives/25274665#25274665) without having to inject `$rootScope` (which i was annoyed about especially communicating with siblings and components that appear in a different hierarchy). Probably you could implement that kind of a wrapper and place the event name check...

Comment: @PSL thank you, I liked your service. Can I also subscribe to events with $scope and not $rootScope inside the service? Passing the scope as argument?

Comment: You mean inside the pubsub service ? The point of placing it in rootscope is that you have the method available in any `$scope`s except for isolated scope since they are not inherited. But you should be able to inject the service and pass in scope calling initialize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do that things: just write your wrapper, that will register events

This is just example of idea

```
angular.service("EventManager", function($rootScope){

  var events_names = {};

  return {
      on: function(name, cb){
        if(!events_names[name]){
            $rootScope.$on(name, cb);
        }
        else{
            console.error("This kind of event already defined!", name);
        }
      }
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no angular way to do so. But you could always write a wrapper fro $broadcast/$emit that has a registry for your event names.