# Observing changes across controllers in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, observer-pattern

I have an angular application with two controller. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
var app = angular.module('walkerApp', ['firebase']);

app.controller('AuthenticationController', function($scope) {
    function login(user) {
      ...
    }
});

app.controller('StepsDataController', function($scope) {

});
```

The StepsDataController serves up data from a firebase backend. The AuthenticationController handles user management. When the current user changes (via the login or register methods of the AuthenticationController,) the StepsDataController should rebind to a  set of data specific to that user.

How do I do this in Angular? Obviously, I need some sort of observer implementation, but I'm not sure what the mechanism is.

Comment: Although I'm not sure, it seems to me that `StepsDataController` should be a service, not an app controller - is there a reason its a controller?

Comment: You could use eventing or you can implement a [pub/sub as in this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274563/angularjs-communication-between-directives/25274665#25274665).

Comment: I simplified out the service, which needs to know what portion of the data hive to look at depending on the currently logged-in user.

Comment: When an the user changes via Authentication controller, you need to refresh the other controller? In reality you have a service which `StepsDataController` uses to fetch the current user information and both the controllers are on the same page at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use `$scope.$broadcast` or `$scope.$emit` from the subject controller, and `$scope.$on` on the observer controller. See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) for more.

I'm not sure how your controllers scopes are related hierarchy wise, but you can always user `$rootScope.$broadcast`.