# Targeting ES5 with TypeScript in IntelliJ IDEA 14

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

I want to use getters and setters in Typescript. At the moment when I try this I get the following:

```
error TS1056: Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.
```

How do I configure my compiler in IntelliJ 14? 
Are there any disadvantages to this? DOes this produce a different type of Javascript that will only work on certain browsers?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To change the compiler options you need to go to the FileWatcher Dialogue.

Settings -> Tools -> File Watchers

Select TypeScript and hit the edit (pencil) button.

Add

```
--target es5
```

to the arguments field

Comment: Just in case you switch to Webstorm 10 and you are looking for the same thing you would have to go: Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> Typescript. And then inside "Command line options" insert `--target es5`

Comment: You'll also do the same thing as the comment from **George Pligor** about webstorm in IntelliJ 14.1

Answer (score 11):

You can set the target version in your tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) is a list of all the compiler options.

Comment: I think, this is the best solution. It allows to bundle the TypeScript configuration with the source files, independent from any IDE specific settings and/or project files. It also represents the configuration as a whole in a much clearer way.

Comment: To use the tsconfig.json in your WebStorm project, go to File -> Settings... -> Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript and switch from 'Set options manually' to 'Use tsconfig.json'.

Answer (score 3):

Setup the watcher to use the compiler flag `--target es5`.

> Are there any disadvantages to this?

Properties (getter/setter) are not supported where es5 isn't supported (obsolete versions of browsers : see http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/)

Comment: Thanks for that, I had seen that compiler flag already but have no idea where to set it. Thanks for the browser compatibility info.

Answer (score -2):

I solved mine by compiling the file in command prompt using "**tsc --target ES5 YourFile.ts**"

Comment: The question is specifically about IntelliJ IDEA 14