# $scope.on not listening to $emit and $broadcast

Tags: angularjs

I'm unable to get the controller to listen to any emit or broadcast messages.
I've tried with $rootScope as well but still it is not working.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
</div>
<div ng-controller="Controller1">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
</div> 

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'SomeName';
  $scope.$broadcast($scope.name, "Hello");
});

app.controller('Controller1', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'SomeName';
  $scope.$on($scope.name, function(event,data) {
    console.log("identified"); 
    console.log("data");
  });
});
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/E95Ucn5Xa9zauwg4dsIA?p=preview

Comment: You could take a look at creating a pub/sub service of your own as well in order to avoid injecting rootScope in many places. You can find a [similar implementation here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274563/angularjs-communication-between-directives/25274665#25274665).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option B

If you want to broadcast event between siblings controllers you can use $rootScope and the rest like in @dfsq answer

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
  $scope.name = 'SomeName';
  $timeout(function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast($scope.name, "Hello");
  }, 1);
});

app.controller('Controller1', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'SomeName';
  $scope.$on($scope.name, function(event, data) {
    console.log("identified");
    console.log("data");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="Controller1">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all since [`$broadcast`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) sends event downwards to child scopes, you need to nest `Controller1` under `MainCtrl` for your approach to work.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <div ng-controller="Controller1">
        <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second nuance is that you are trying to broadcast event right away in `MainCtrl` controller, however at this time `$scope.$on` is not yet registered in `Controller1`, so dispatching event in this manner makes little sense as there is nothing to handle it yet. But for the sake of demonstration, if you broadcast event after some timeout or on `ngClick`, you will see that it works properly.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/wo1IHggq9CiDHPVcgB4C?p=info

Answer (score 0):

```
It needs Parent-> Child or Child-> Parent relationship but you are creating two isolated Divs.
```

Nest one  with another then it will work.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <div ng-controller="Controller1">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here MainCntrl will be Parent of Controller1

Or

```
<div ng-controller="Controller1">
      <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here Controller1 will be Parent controller of MainCntrl