# Defining my own 'require' on a directive, but throw error - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let us say I have this **html**:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">    
    <br>
    <my-directive my-name="name">Hello, {{name}}!</my-directive>
</div>
```

with this simple **controller**:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
});
```

And I have a directive in which I want to change the `'name'` using `require` like this:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
var controller = ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Steve";
}];
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: 'myName',
        controller: controller,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, TheCtrl) {
            TheCtrl.$render = function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    TheCtrl.$setViewValue('StackOverflow');  
                }, 2000);                
            };
        }
    };
});
```

But throws:

> `Error: No controller: myName`

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2GAS/104/)

---

But if I implement it using **ng-model**, works. Look here in this other [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2GAS/102/)

I have [read](https://www.nadeau.tv/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/) that if you use `'require'` in a directive, you need to have a controller for it.

So:

What I'm doing is wrong? It is not in this way? I need to do any other thing?

Comment: The error tells you what the problem is, myName is not a controller.  Require is looking for a controller, and 'my-name' is simply an attribute you have defined on 'my-directive'

Comment: Explain what you expect this `require` to do? With the limited code shown it doesn't make sense to use it at all

Comment: @Brian Have you see the second fiddle? Compare both fiddle's, and then tell me again. `require: 'ngModel',` is a directive, that has it's own controller: [ngModel.NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Comment: @charlietfl I'm just practicing. I just want to know if I can use `require` inside a directive with my own attr (in this case my-name)? Or just only I can use `require` with `ng-model`?

Comment: @charlietfl I think that `my-name` has to be a directive, as I read on the link I showed on my question. Is this true?

Comment: no...`require` has nothing to do with attributes. Also `$setViewValue` has nothing to do with text...it is an `ng-model` method related to setting form control values

Comment: and yes... `my-name` would have to be a directive that has a controller. Lots of directives don't even use controllers

Comment: @charlietfl Well, I think I have to practice a little more. When I have an answer, I'll be back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally I got it.

Essencially what I'm trying to do is something called: **'Communication between directives using controllers'**. I have found an [article](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/directive-to-directive-communication) explaining this, and helped me a lot:

**The view:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <br>
 <my-directive my-name>Hello, {{name}}!</my-directive>
</div>
```

As you see above, there are two directives: `my-directive` and `my-name`. I will call inside `my-directive` a function from the controller of `my-name` directive using `require`.

**myDirective:**

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
 return {
  require: 'myName',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, myNameCtrl) {
   $timeout(function() {
    myNameCtrl.setName("Steve");
   }, 9000);
  } // End of link
 }; // return
});
```

**myName:**

```
myApp.directive('myName', function($timeout) {
    var controller = ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        // As I tried, this function can be only accessed from 'link' inside this directive
        $scope.setName = function(name) {
            $scope.name = name;
            console.log("Inside $scope.setName defined in the directive myName");
        };

        // As I tried, this function can accessed from inside/outside of this directive
        this.setName = function(name) {
            $scope.name = name;
            console.log("Inside this.setName defined in the directive myName");
        };
    }];

    return {
        controller: controller,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, localCtrl) {
            $timeout(function() {
                localCtrl.setName("Charles");
            }, 3000);
            $timeout(function() {
                scope.setName("David");
            }, 6000);
        } // End of link function
    };
});
```

Interesting and works like a charm. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2GAS/107/) if you want to try it out.

Also, you can get communication between directives using *events*. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25274665/2954267) here on SO.